# Orchard CMS ISessionConfigurationEvents and 1:N, N:N Relationships?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, many-to-many, orchardcms, one-to-many

I have spent many days trying to implement relationships within OrchardCMS 1.9.1 between my custom contentParts to no avail.
Strewn across the internet are many others trying to achieve the same thing, who have also failed; giving me the impression that it's impossible?
Though recently I read an article at: http://www.ideliverable.com/blog/isessionconfigurationevents that gave the impression that all things possible with Fluent Nhibernate should be possible within Orchard.

So I implemented:

```
public class DbMapping : ISessionConfigurationEvents
{
    public void Created(FluentConfiguration cfg, AutoPersistenceModel defaultModel)
    {
        defaultModel.UseOverridesFromAssemblyOf<ProfilePartRecord>().Alterations(x => x.AddFromAssemblyOf<ProfileOverride>());
        defaultModel.UseOverridesFromAssemblyOf<LocationPartRecord>().Alterations(x => x.AddFromAssemblyOf<LocationOverride>());
    }

    public void Prepared(FluentConfiguration cfg) { }
    public void Building(Configuration cfg) { }
    public void Finished(Configuration cfg) { }
    public void ComputingHash(Hash hash) { }
}



public class LocationOverride : IAutoMappingOverride<LocationPartRecord>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<LocationPartRecord> mapping)
    {
        //[ Profile ] <--> [ Location ]
        //mapping.Id(x => x.Id, "LocationPartRecord_id"); //As it's not in the model due to being a contentPart, NH will throw an error because of such.
        mapping.Map(x => x.Type);
        mapping.Map(x => x.Name);
        mapping.References(x => x.ProfilePartRecord, "ProfilePartRecord_id");
    }
}


public class ProfileOverride : IAutoMappingOverride<ProfilePartRecord>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<ProfilePartRecord> mapping)
    {
        //[ Profile ] 0.1 <---> N [ Location ]
        //NEW
        mapping.HasMany(x => x.Locations)
            .Inverse()
            //.KeyColumn("ProfilePartRecord_id")
            .Cascade.All()
            .ForeignKeyCascadeOnDelete() 
            .ForeignKeyConstraintName("FK_Location__Profile"); 
    }
}
```

MODELS:

```
public class ProfilePartRecord : ContentPartRecord
{
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }

    [CascadeAllDeleteOrphan]
    public virtual IList<LocationPartRecord> Locations { get; set; }
    public ProfilePartRecord()
    {
        Locations = new List<LocationPartRecord>();
    }
}


public class LocationPartRecord : ContentPartRecord
{
    public virtual string Type { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    //For HasMany
    [CascadeAllDeleteOrphan]
    public virtual ProfilePartRecord ProfilePartRecord { get; set; }
}
```

MIGRATION:

```
        SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("ProfilePartRecord",
            table => table
                .ContentPartRecord()
                //PK: ProfilePartRecord_id
                .Column<string>("FirstName")
                .Column<string>("LastName")
                //System
                .Column<DateTime>("CreatedAt")
            );

        ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition("ProfilePart",
            builder => builder.Attachable());

        ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition("Profile", t => t
            .WithPart(typeof(ProfilePart).Name)
            .WithPart("UserPart")
            );

        ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition("User", t => t
            .WithPart("ProfilePart")
            );



        SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("LocationPartRecord",
            table => table
                .ContentPartRecord()
                //PK: LocationPartRecord_id
                //FK:
                .Column<int>("ProfilePartRecord_id")
                .Column<string>("Type")
                .Column<string>("Name")
                //System
                .Column<DateTime>("CreatedAt")
            );

        ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition("LocationPart",
            builder => builder.Attachable());

        ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition("Location", type => type
            .WithPart("CommonPart")
            .WithPart("LocationPart")
            .Creatable()
            .Listable());
```

But alas, I still can't create a relationship between these two entities. I can do such via Migration, but this is very limited - as in - I can't set the relationship to Cascade.

Can anyone shed some light on whether this is possible, and if so, how? Thanks

Comment: There's an Orchard guide to foreign keys: http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Creating-1-n-and-n-n-relations However, I didn't find any cascades there.

Answer (score 0):

This may not get you the whole way, but I believe it will help. One thing I have done for performance reasons as well as to establish relationships at the database level between my parts is to use the "CreateForeignKey" and "CreateIndex" in the Migration. Here is an example that should work for you

```
// Add foreign key
SchemaBuilder.CreateForeignKey(
    "FK_LocationProfile",
    "LocationPartRecord", new[] { "ProfilePartRecord_id" },
    "ProfilePartRecord", new[] { "Id" });

// Add index
SchemaBuilder.AlterTable("LocationPartRecord",
    table => table
        .CreateIndex("IDX_ProfilePartRecord_Id", "ProfilePartRecord_Id")
    );
```

With these relationships defined, I wonder if that will in any way impact the NHibernate work you are doing.

As for how we have done the overall goal I believe you are trying to achieve, you can monitor the "ProfilePart" "Delete" event in the "LocationPart" handler and apply your own cascading delete logic there to ensure that there are no "LocationPart" left around.

Comment: Yeah, the above is what I was referring to when I mentioned “via migration” – but alas, it doesn’t help the cause; of which, I believe is futile.  For it seems like a lot of work for probably not a lot of ‘functional gain’.  Therefore, I think your concept is ultimately where I should head…do you have any sample code regarding the Handler side of things – I’ve been perusing Orchard Modules and have probably gotten myself a little confused, as some seem to use:
            OnUnpublishing(); //or
            OnDestroying();
How did you go about it? Thanks for all your help, cheers